# Exportar imagenes de html a word

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word

Partiendo de mi anterior [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65242/exportar-html-a-word), me gustaria saber como puedo exportar una imagen de html a Word, o por lo menos saber si es posible o no.

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
 <table id="test" class="table table-striped table-custom table-responsive">            
            <tbody id="tablabody">              
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:33.333333%">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-custom table-responsive">            
                            <tbody>             
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="/html/images/chico64.png" /></td>                 
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Nombre: IKER</td>
                                    <td>Apellido: IKER</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>                    
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:33.333333%">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-custom table-responsive">            
                            <tbody>             
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="/html/images/chico64.png" /></td>                 
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Nombre: ANDONI</td>
                                    <td>Apellido: ANDONI</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>                    
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:33.333333%">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-custom table-responsive">            
                            <tbody>             
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="/html/images/chica64.png" /></td>                 
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Nombre: ERIKA</td>
                                    <td>Apellido: ERIKA</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>                    
                    </td>                                       
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

La exporto con un botón que llama al siguiente método:

```
function creaWord(){    
var html = document.getElementById("test").outerHTML;
  var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
    type: 'application/msword'
  });
  var href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = href;
  a.download = "documento.doc";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'documento.doc');
  } else {
    a.click();
  }
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Esto me exporta correctamente a word el formato de la tabla, pero las imágenes me las exporta de esta manera. No se ni si se puede exportar imágenes a word de esta manera. Pero por lo menos aclarar si es posible o no, y si es posible como debería hacerlo.
[image]

## Edicion

Hay un [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/ga8g6v9p/) que usa una librería externa y exporta imagenes. En un principio puede ser una solución valida pero me gustaría hacerlo sin usar librerías externas.

Por otra parte,he visto que en este jsfiddle convierte la imagen a base64 pero he probado ha hacer lo mismo (sin usar la librería) para ver si era cosa de la codificación pero sigue sin funcionar.

## Edicion 2

Después de ver la baja calidad de mis resultados con javascript estoy probando a hacerlo con php.

Lo primero que he hecho es que el botón llame a la siguiente página php.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=documento.doc");

echo "<html>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">
<style> 
@page
{
    size:21cm 29.7cmt;  /* A4 */
    margin:1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm; /* Margins: 2.5 cm on each side */
    mso-page-orientation: portrait; 
}
@page Section1 { }
div.Section1 { page:Section1; }
p.MsoHeader, p.MsoFooter { border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
<body>
<div class=Section1>
<table id='test' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>            
    <tr>
        <td class='col-4' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
            <div class='row' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                <div class='col-6' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                    <img id='img-0' src='/html/images/chico64.png' />
                </div>
                <div class='col-6' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                    <h1>1</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                <div class='col-12' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                    Carrero Gomez, Iker
                </div>                      
            </div>
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>";
?>
```

Hasta aquí todo funciona relativamente bien pero tengo dos problemas.

1. El word se abre con la vista de diseño web, me gustaria saber como evitar esto y que se abra como un word normal.
2. Las imágenes siguen sin exportarse.

La documentación para saber que estilos debo aplicar estoy usando esta [página](http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?id=word_document_generation#examples) pero aún así creo que algunos como el salto de página no me terminan de funcionar.

Comment: @frikinside creo que te pasas de graciosete cuando ni si quiera te habrás molestado en mirar mi código y ver que lo que quiero hacer hay que implementarlo a uno función que esta hecha. Y lo mejor aun que ni si quiera te has parado a mirar los resultados de google por que lo que sale no me sirve para nada.

Comment: Más razón que un santo. Tenía una serie de pestañas abiertas y copié el título y comenté en donde no tocaba. Un despiste tonto más dañino que otra cosa.

Comment: Exactamente, quieres: 1. - Exportar la imagen a un archivo ms-word con la imagen *incrustada* o *enlazada*. 2. - Descargar la imagen **sola e individual** al equipo del cliente.

Comment: Ah, vale. Lo primero. Que no leí la pregunta completa. *Mea culpa* :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es convirtiendo las imágenes a base64. Si las imágenes están en tu servidor no vas a tener problemas con CORS (cross-origin resource sharing).

Le di un id a las imágenes

```
...<img id="img-0" src="/html/images/chico64.png" />...
...<img id="img-1" src="/html/images/chico64.png" />...
...<img id="img-2" src="/html/images/chica64.png" />...
```

Esta es la función que convierte el enlace con la imágen a base64:

```
function imgUrlABase64(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      callback(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
}
```

Modifiqué tu función creaWord para reemplazar el src de la imágen a base64. Simplemente reemplaza el enlace en el src por la codificación a base64. Mira a ver que el `.replace` encuentra y reemplaza el src correctamente. Asegurate que `urlBase + document.getElementById("img-0")` es el enlace con la imágen.

```
function creaWord(){        
    var html = document.getElementById("test").outerHTML;

    // -----------------------------------------------
    // CONVERTIR IMG SRC A BASE64
    var urlBase = window.location.href;
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=img-]');
    for (var i in imgs){
        imgUrlABase64(document.getElementById("img-0").src, 
            function(dataURL){
                html = html.replace(urlBase + document.getElementById("img-"+i), dataURL); 
            }
        );
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------


    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });
    var href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = href;
    a.download = "documento.doc";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'documento.doc');
    } else {
        a.click();
    }
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Si las imágenes no están en tu servidor mira a ver si alguna de estas otras soluciones te ayudan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

**EDICION 2**

Esta es la respuesta usando PHP con la solución del OP en su **Edición 2** y el estilo necesario para que el documento se abra en Word como texto y no como Web Layout.

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=documento.doc");

    echo "<html 
            xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'
            xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' 
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">
    <head>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <xml>
            <w:WordDocument>
            <w:View>Print</w:View>
            <w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom> 
            <w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
            </w:WordDocument>
            </xml>
        <![endif]-->
    <style> 
    @page
    {
        size:21cm 29.7cmt;  /* A4 */
        margin:1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm; /* Margins: 2.5 cm on each side */
        mso-page-orientation: portrait; 
    }
    @page Section1 {
        size:21cm 29.7cm;  /* A4 */
        margin:1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm; /* Margins: 2.5 cm on each side */
        mso-header-margin: 2cm;
        mso-footer-margin: 2cm;
        mso-paper-source:0;
        mso-page-orientation: portrait; 
    }
    div.Section1 { page:Section1; }
    p.MsoHeader, p.MsoFooter { border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class=Section1>
    <table id='test' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>            
        <tr>
            <td class='col-4' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                <div class='row' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                    <div class='col-6' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                        <img id='img-0' src='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/html/images/chico64.png' />
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-6' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                        <h1>1</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                    <div class='col-12' style='  border: 1px solid black;'>
                        Carrero Gomez, Iker
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>";
?>
```

Comment: He probado con tu metodo y nada, la imagen sigue sin exportase, he comprobado el replace y si el `getElementById` funciona. El `getElementById` no encuentra la imagen, el script lo tengo al final de la pagina. El `replace` he puesto un `console.log` para saber que me debuelbe, este es el resultado `http://192.168.7.29/txartelak.php[object HTMLImageElement]` nose si el correcto o no.

Comment: Aquí  (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7341/Dynamically-generate-a-MS-Word-document-using-HTML) hay un ejemplo del estilo que necesitas incluir para que se abra como una págia Word normal.

Comment: Si actualizas tu respuesta, con el código de mi respuesta para las imágenes y con el estilo que se necesita incluir la acepto.

Comment: @AndoniAlda Le añadí a mi respuesta el código en tu Edición 2 junto con el estilo para que se abra como un página Word normal. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Por ahora he conseguido arreglar el problema de las imagenes, pero se mantiene el problema de que word abre el documento en la vista que no quiero.

El problema de las imagenes era mas sencillo de lo que en un principio parecia, habia probado a convertirlas e insertala de distintas maneras.

Al final lo he solucionado cambiando lo que en un principio era esta linea.

`<img id='img-0' src='/html/images/chico64.png' />`

a esta

`<img id='img-0' src='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/html/images/chico64.png' />`