# Elegir la vista con la que se abre Word al exportar

Tags: php, html, ms-word

Estoy realizando una exportación a Word con php, despues de hacer un esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65242/exportar-html-a-word) y [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65580/exportar-imagenes-de-html-a-word) he conseguido hacer la exportación de manera correcta. Pero me falta un detalle (por ahora, me parece que este tema va a ir para largo).

Cuando abro el word exportado este se abre en vista web [image: Vista Web] pero yo necesito que se abra en la vista normal [image: Vista normal].

El código para generar el documento word es este:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=documento.doc");

echo "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">
<style>
<!--@page
    {size:21cm 29.7cmt;}

 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:'Cambria Math';
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;
    mso-font-charset:1;
    mso-generic-font-family:roman;
    mso-font-format:other;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:-520081665 -1073717157 41 0 66047 0;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-parent:'';
    margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:'Times New Roman','serif';
    mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman';
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;}
h1
    {mso-style-priority:9;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-link:'Título 1 Car';
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0cm;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0cm;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    mso-outline-level:1;
    font-size:24.0pt;
    font-family:'Times New Roman','serif';
    mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman';
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;}
p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:'Encabezado Car';
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0cm;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0cm;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    border:none;
    mso-border-alt:solid black .75pt;
    padding:0cm;
    mso-padding-alt:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:'Times New Roman','serif';
    mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman';
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;}
p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:'Pie de página Car';
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0cm;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0cm;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    border:none;
    mso-border-alt:solid black .75pt;
    padding:0cm;
    mso-padding-alt:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:'Times New Roman','serif';
    mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman';
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;}
p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:'Texto de globo Car';
    margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-family:'Tahoma','sans-serif';
    mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman';
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;}
span.EncabezadoCar
    {mso-style-name:'Encabezado Car';
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-locked:yes;
    mso-style-link:Encabezado;
    mso-ansi-font-size:12.0pt;
    mso-bidi-font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:'Times New Roman','serif';
    mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman';
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;}
span.PiedepginaCar
    {mso-style-name:'Pie de página Car';
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-locked:yes;
    mso-style-link:'Pie de página';
    mso-ansi-font-size:12.0pt;
    mso-bidi-font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:'Times New Roman','serif';
    mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman';
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;}
span.Ttulo1Car
    {mso-style-name:'Título 1 Car';
    mso-style-priority:9;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-locked:yes;
    mso-style-link:'Título 1';
    mso-ansi-font-size:14.0pt;
    mso-bidi-font-size:14.0pt;
    font-family:'Cambria','serif';
    mso-ascii-font-family:Cambria;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:major-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman';
    mso-fareast-theme-font:major-fareast;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Cambria;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:'Times New Roman';
    mso-bidi-theme-font:major-bidi;
    color:#365F91;
    mso-themecolor:accent1;
    mso-themeshade:191;
    font-weight:bold;}
span.TextodegloboCar
    {mso-style-name:'Texto de globo Car';
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-locked:yes;
    mso-style-link:'Texto de globo';
    mso-ansi-font-size:8.0pt;
    mso-bidi-font-size:8.0pt;
    font-family:'Tahoma','sans-serif';
    mso-ascii-font-family:Tahoma;
    mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman';
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-fareast;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Tahoma;
    mso-bidi-font-family:Tahoma;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    mso-default-props:yes;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    mso-ansi-font-size:10.0pt;
    mso-bidi-font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:595.3pt 841.9pt;
    margin:1.0cm 1.0cm 1.0cm 1.0cm;
    mso-header-margin:35.4pt;
    mso-footer-margin:35.4pt;
    mso-paper-source:0;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>
<body>
<div class=Section1>
<table class=MsoTableGrid border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
    style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
    mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>

    <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>

        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p><img id='img-0' src='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/html/images/chico64.png' /></o:p></span></p>
        </td>       
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:
        solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p><h1>1</h1></o:p></span></p>
        </td>

        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
        mso-border-right-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>

        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:
        solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>       
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:
        solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>

        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
        mso-border-right-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>       
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:
        solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:
        solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1'>
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
        padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;
        border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
        mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
        mso-border-right-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;
        border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
        mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;
        border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
        mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
        mso-border-right-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;
        border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
        mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=91 valign=top style='width:68.2pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;
        border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
        mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman''><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>";

?>
```

Adjunto todo porque realmente nose en que parte se le especifica al word donde debe abrirse (en los estilos, cabecera o contenido).